# Python: Calculate the average speed and the standard deviation of every timestep

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have the following problem. I have a list of arrays. In every array are a different number of speed values for a cell. Now i want to calculate the average speed for each timestep for all cells. Some of the cells do move at specific time or disappear and the arrays are not of the same length. Some has 60 timesteps, other only 20 or 2. How can i calculate this?

```
stepwiseSpeed = [array([ 1.55858028,  1.72319652,  1.3138632 , ...,  1.21889017,
        0.89490572,  0.57537662]), array([ 1.91378539,  1.94151339,  2.32322109, ...,  1.67023367,
        1.82005941,  2.11918622]), array([ 1.33111955,  1.32013105,  1.58057118, ...,  1.39378854,
        1.57944246,  0.9993698 ]), array([ 0.49445374,  0.55514075,  0.67257435, ...,  1.14848269,
        1.04420137,  1.07907484]), array([ 2.54790115,  2.35476761,  2.2023148 , ...,  0.9137895 ,
        0.66586954,  0.8247339 ]), array([ 1.54280143,  1.32324648,  1.50265473, ...,  0.76789729,
        1.35688697,  2.33849316]), array([ 0.16252154,  0.04299128,  0.29318296, ...,  0.38305124,
        0.39047567,  0.46256891]), array([ 0.25298221,  0.41818806,  0.33350037, ...,  0.65907682,
        0.83928452,  0.39371468]), array([ 1.09880219,  1.01478976,  0.91687649, ...,  1.02647455,
        1.24970487,  2.01485763]), array([ 0.09464143,  1.61802874,  1.49291569, ...,  1.76469325,
        1.14202627,  0.71533366]), array([ 1.60550031,  1.73888988,  2.21143692,  2.3515708 ,  2.18094274,
        2.09998345,  2.21021413,  1.76824263]), array([ 1.34700937,  1.42637381,  1.59221112, ...,  1.30645599,
        1.54239716,  1.35439913]), array([ 1.89335819,  2.08723573,  1.57333285, ...,  2.11308856,
        1.47246027,  1.15664612]), array([ 1.12155082,  0.92655882,  1.09706882, ...,  0.77595183,
        1.63657821,  0.75386007]), array([ 2.49641528,  2.49097636,  1.96445323, ...,  2.6539554 ,
        2.81124034,  2.14660301]), array([ 0.77921708,  0.9108684 ,  1.518581  , ...,  1.38129088,
        1.29851386,  1.73863948]), array([ 2.00074417,  1.9842234 ,  2.00441045, ...,  2.17050622,
        1.88565884,  1.03864166]), array([ 3.53476407,  2.73784518,  2.25230393, ...,  0.7960468 ,
        1.77199217,  2.19730864]), array([ 1.53449153,  2.57789691,  1.45867414, ...,  2.22159633,
        1.59388394,  1.22748238]), array([ 0.36409477,  2.35263363,  2.12942533,  2.34612894,  2.47864605]), array([ 2.17469504,  1.64095125,  2.16791075, ...,  2.07901635,
        1.84478427,  2.53679483]), array([ 1.56738652,  1.56266927,  0.67997004, ...,  1.78691361,
        2.09958669,  1.59975561]), array([ 1.20872247,  1.6410732 ,  1.89742411]), array([ 0.20453362,  0.11991351,  0.12212289, ...,  0.08566359,
        0.05703069,  0.29739704]), array([ 1.75904022,  2.09773408,  1.79617517, ...,  0.82287378,
        1.36801069,  1.51320562]), array([ 0.05261179,  0.46579663]), array([ 0.23269777,  1.90598072,  1.56422417, ...,  0.3680197 ,
        0.357694  ,  0.06367496]), array([ 1.01395513,  0.98519541,  1.07660601, ...,  0.9802617 ,
        0.76729655,  0.96600945]), array([ 1.33202637,  0.7318615 ,  1.1559628 , ...,  1.03510893,
        1.26631947,  1.48354786]), array([ 1.0866606 ,  0.77068882,  0.88053223, ...,  1.90948219,
        2.21011476,  1.97420224]), array([ 2.12812975,  2.01956097,  2.31859661, ...,  1.94602891,
        1.85868509,  1.74235258]), array([ 1.76357854,  1.43027873,  1.48372378, ...,  1.8284423 ,
        2.08478086,  1.2062364 ]), array([ 0.30522   ,  0.07227206,  0.10364   , ...,  0.20251049,
        0.17750282,  0.20282135]), array([ 2.69737326,  1.79450223,  1.81635191, ...,  2.31043205,
        1.76532405,  2.16768921]), array([ 0.26849069,  0.18535506,  0.04669047, ...,  0.57618508,
        0.75687466,  0.10831667]), array([ 2.18284476,  3.10184336,  2.73087605, ...,  2.10712339,
        2.0009146 ,  1.67278458]), array([ 2.6001824 ,  2.96293136,  3.03568485, ...,  2.12006226,
        2.64044409,  2.46736889]), array([ 0.9525294 ,  0.81262322,  1.24229546, ...,  0.9767913 ,
        0.51150611,  0.79479589]), array([ 0.25192161,  0.40685378,  0.22003295, ...,  1.37511136,
        0.93462987,  0.45534438]), array([ 1.9968668 ,  1.8816708 ,  1.52276344, ...,  0.45460422,
        0.8757444 ,  0.60405981]), array([ 0.86648024,  0.56151425,  0.29774234, ...,  1.12381682,
        1.2909269 ,  2.86136895]), array([ 0.62895548,  0.83833913,  0.86012688, ...,  0.95821462,
        0.78016617,  0.77060042]), array([ 0.43987726,  0.05630275,  0.18917783, ...,  0.075316  ,
        0.52368311,  0.12119509]), array([ 0.32087575,  0.06232576]), array([ 1.13415222,  1.21691341,  1.70172596, ...,  0.98508794,
        1.18055855,  2.08319478]), array([ 0.30171054,  0.10151108,  0.13138588, ...,  0.28987109,
        0.41692325,  0.70072124]), array([ 1.23198265,  0.98577102,  0.93972403, ...,  0.8060411 ,
        0.57367805,  0.55542101]), array([ 1.9453846 ,  1.93433774,  1.95535348, ...,  1.71128607,
        1.69986066,  1.99904802]), array([ 0.41382907,  0.13898291,  0.0505099 , ...,  0.20115914,
        0.1050488 ,  0.18561385]), array([ 0.38006907,  0.30888914,  0.25646247, ...,  0.05544367,
        0.08395237,  0.65774862]), array([ 0.2860354 ,  0.11174301,  0.1454132 , ...,  0.10700117,
        0.2100976 ,  0.20984756]), array([ 1.53951681,  1.2273341 ,  1.24489809, ...,  1.47022532,
        1.50214189,  1.63154788]), array([ 0.99671862,  1.36467505,  1.17222694, ...,  1.60129674,
        1.05191171,  1.29765192]), array([ 0.15404951,  0.10419813,  0.0985    , ...,  0.14107179,
        0.14647867,  0.04180012]), array([ 0.28887065,  0.1084493 ,  0.11624543, ...,  0.45650192,
        0.56707142,  0.28541417]), array([ 2.26928414,  1.25146075,  1.47439386, ...,  2.60592695,
        1.27440437,  1.87131672]), array([ 2.92374199,  1.46373563,  1.80281981, ...,  2.19150006,
        2.25192146,  1.90295139]), array([ 2.18285919,  1.68016011,  1.40383136, ...,  0.42678625,
        1.25455271,  0.38832074]), array([ 3.02971764,  2.74982045,  1.8573224 , ...,  2.40567215,
        2.23071659,  1.80791683]), array([ 1.48257757,  1.29211184,  1.48204698, ...,  2.66644656,
        2.10154289,  1.17909648]), array([ 2.03090356,  2.20390024,  1.81261034, ...,  1.81366018,
        2.36686396,  3.11423377]), array([ 1.76671793,  1.82343261,  1.41152152, ...,  2.21197344,
        1.61988155,  1.75330146]), array([ 1.12100602,  1.39713609,  1.05732966, ...,  0.81416122,
        1.79136994,  1.20562867]), array([ 0.12583819,  0.18826179,  0.02466779, ...,  0.22483883,
        0.22450891,  0.03037269]), array([ 1.87311038,  1.90238436,  1.58469973, ...,  1.9883275 ,
        1.73602074,  1.56803141]), array([ 1.86455745,  1.81486398,  1.48632407, ...,  1.36969212,
        1.00423565,  1.0501563 ]), array([ 2.73055786,  1.83777563,  1.85286137, ...,  2.24384815,
        2.29956893,  2.31718471]), array([ 1.89764341,  1.70214872,  1.84366598,  1.69067331,  1.63166556,
        1.57210718,  2.0997838 ,  0.5       ]), array([ 2.88394868,  1.76794683,  1.84730412, ...,  1.67066791,
        2.20931828,  3.14142364]), array([ 2.21248983,  2.04950945,  1.99745063, ...,  1.74589211,
        1.37430391,  0.65894044]), array([ 2.44579256,  3.        ,  2.90203726, ...,  2.22868913,
        2.30628576,  2.55041418]), array([ 1.68212306,  1.4199279 ,  1.20669155, ...,  2.49021455,
        2.35037364,  2.39554091]), array([ 1.06665189,  1.11918508,  0.7972208 , ...,  1.60282813,
        1.58208533,  2.19066457]), array([ 0.78931109,  1.13041054,  1.16357477, ...,  2.66146163,
        2.43427053,  2.23752419]), array([ 2.19094643,  1.76558574,  1.37872767,  0.82824211,  2.18727027,
        2.62784099]), array([ 0.10083774,  0.43023395,  0.19314502, ...,  0.55084526,
        0.18818209,  0.33118575]), array([ 1.22523885,  1.1780226 ,  1.16143898, ...,  1.37054305,
        1.27952735,  1.66479338]), array([ 0.1667708 ,  0.19700063,  0.06909595, ...,  0.11294357,
        0.14055693,  0.19833368]), array([ 0.27619649,  0.09141116,  0.07320007, ...,  0.49362992,
        0.1314962 ,  0.23830076]), array([ 1.67102162,  1.62518745,  1.98942636, ...,  1.45618723,
        0.337855  ,  1.66846674]), array([ 0.60795991,  0.44838739,  0.38203796, ...,  0.46585942,
        0.30358401,  0.73156357]), array([ 1.07226862,  0.78236069,  0.73008647, ...,  1.18012425,
        2.05000006,  1.35999559]), array([ 0.49515351,  0.34681443,  0.57254039, ...,  1.12471385,
        0.88768252,  0.37862415]), array([ 0.43722134,  1.31378784,  1.28410767, ...,  0.22951961,
        0.1011002 ,  0.13063786]), array([ 1.58778919,  0.91317975,  1.3874045 , ...,  0.67955371,
        1.56955766,  1.84941207]), array([ 1.38600081,  0.71548463,  1.1139072 , ...,  1.7361188 ,
        1.09014047,  1.67402337]), array([ 2.33964084,  2.2881121 ,  2.64705969, ...,  2.54892414,
        2.3285146 ,  3.00123183]), array([ 2.93343459,  2.78420698,  3.37859161, ...,  2.13336835,
        1.99106655,  2.74309697]), array([ 2.03878156,  1.97883665,  1.779593  , ...,  1.69101892,
        1.77543185,  1.60652552]), array([ 1.84313381,  2.33591765,  2.26208267, ...,  1.83826991,
        1.81539837,  1.66015007]), array([ 0.32584812,  0.12905909,  0.10983624, ...,  0.08502353,
        0.02263846,  0.16272216]), array([ 2.08540224,  2.52326103,  1.78199502, ...,  1.43025566,
        2.10360892,  2.50847209]), array([ 1.35194989,  1.00768299,  1.06636731, ...,  1.07219984,
        2.88258604,  2.13120324]), array([ 0.97252044,  1.74217981,  1.53105299, ...,  2.04182596,
        2.23229221,  2.309091  ]), array([ 1.41432245,  1.86468771,  1.77704396, ...,  0.95134549,
        1.31210156,  0.69083464]), array([ 2.24700801,  2.08037316,  2.02301044, ...,  1.45537504,
        2.23908045,  2.63455883]), array([ 0.82991641,  1.86141431,  2.34076531, ...,  1.10209584,
        0.92174847,  0.97488012]), array([ 0.38514316,  0.21352752,  0.25347436, ...,  0.07790058,
        0.16285346,  0.1315038 ]), array([ 2.02986761,  0.82133809,  1.17532176, ...,  1.28708828,
        1.62466558,  2.66293832]), array([ 0.8934702 ,  0.85802346,  0.89695541, ...,  0.08343411,
        0.16163926,  0.21664545]), array([ 0.33850923,  0.24557687,  0.16454331, ...,  0.22479435,
        0.57760475,  0.41688518]), array([ 1.39075708,  2.9092652 ,  0.99997012, ...,  2.42601984,
        2.08349058,  0.59230482]), array([ 1.97287994,  2.01780977,  2.        , ...,  0.        ,
        0.5       ,  0.        ]), array([ 0.32086641,  1.29471425,  0.04457858, ...,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.5       ]), array([ 2.43895316,  2.83801762,  2.62735456, ...,  1.96420684,
        2.3198847 ,  2.05312749]), array([ 3.02936536,  3.22485054,  2.52072336, ...,  0.76459957,
        0.41013565,  0.45389261]), array([ 0.29225545,  0.17980615,  1.03240556,  1.21714112,  1.18821421,
        0.52382917,  0.82153591,  1.41904061,  2.27450665]), array([ 1.2816858 ,  1.25700358,  1.20278115, ...,  1.61915263,
        1.77364441,  1.30971085]), array([ 1.97751422,  1.95173058,  1.54928661, ...,  1.98322496,
        2.04750488,  2.2632575 ]), array([ 0.63925621,  0.66576892,  0.97573818, ...,  0.12602579,
        0.2588035 ,  0.31642535]), array([ 0.40626223,  0.1778595 ,  0.03687818, ...,  0.13887134,
        0.31905642,  0.4443152 ]), array([ 0.34145644,  0.1360046 ,  0.04825971, ...,  0.03860052,
        0.23750474,  0.17262677]), array([ 0.18390283,  1.48037166,  1.23468427,  1.91344885,  2.13213813,
        1.17380769,  0.28618613,  1.14347333]), array([ 1.22660283,  1.54239465,  1.60848912, ...,  1.05759692,
        1.14263828,  0.64083091]), array([ 2.44351223,  2.59941864,  2.38900785, ...,  1.92910893,
        2.1107687 ,  2.58347581]), array([ 2.05453803,  2.15442811,  1.75392645, ...,  1.27033165,
        2.41534604,  2.00029848]), array([ 0.78288521,  1.48917536,  1.16919673, ...,  1.30538433,
        1.33542587,  1.96086575]), array([ 1.68339575,  1.85524459,  2.07925479, ...,  1.26744033,
        1.1795496 ,  2.08592246]), array([ 0.21437001,  0.20903827,  0.08782084, ...,  0.18694719,
        0.15453964,  0.28100712]), array([ 2.02139958,  1.63307333,  1.38518167, ...,  2.25808353,
        1.90529453,  1.34233844]), array([ 1.92463516,  1.36573286,  1.54907004, ...,  1.65766228,
        1.73290421,  1.35040781]), array([ 0.13159502,  0.14026582,  0.10248902, ...,  0.1916155 ,
        0.60245539,  0.11750106]), array([ 0.63557376,  0.24203306,  0.34270286]), array([ 0.18857691,  0.21780553,  0.15810914, ...,  0.05126646,
        0.13080998,  0.1913276 ]), array([ 1.22705674]), array([ 0.13507128]), array([ 0.2354708]), array([ 1.57633531,  1.55151837,  1.31369422, ...,  1.91784319,
        2.21293391,  1.97695631]), array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  2.09862604, ...,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.5       ]), array([ 0.95880042,  0.66884116,  1.06916042, ...,  2.20919182,
        1.6887334 ,  2.08884777]), array([ 0.21483017,  0.14633694,  0.07961156, ...,  0.50707421,
        0.26750187,  0.28801389]), array([ 1.53528532,  1.30901499]), array([ 0.04164733]), array([ 0.31047423]), array([ 0.19588581,  0.67608062]), array([ 2.43942872,  1.38864862,  1.69930611, ...,  2.72903078,
        2.74475104,  3.03296245]), array([ 0.13336041]), array([ 1.4435943 ,  1.33855332,  1.26706748, ...,  2.52732828,
        1.83266643,  1.19031361]), array([ 0.71127087,  0.54525063,  0.11205467,  0.37567439,  0.54685739,
        0.15082855]), array([ 0.34405232,  0.10654225,  0.22720145, ...,  1.48355317,
        1.2728799 ,  1.53241125]), array([ 2.]), array([ 0.59890442]), array([ 1.26222106,  1.8219377 ]), array([ 0.46585942,  0.76667888,  0.56226373, ...,  0.07724312,
        0.28786499,  0.13753272]), array([ 0.1091444 ,  0.16341665,  0.3989693 ,  0.30698901,  0.24913551,
        0.48188432,  0.51878922,  0.08511903]), array([ 1.87770978]), array([ 2.]), array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0. , ...,  0. ,  0.5,  0. ]), array([ 1.12430067,  1.20262733,  1.41128461, ...,  1.41489505,
        1.09233843,  0.56896507]), array([ 0.4415654 ,  0.21175753,  0.36739624]), array([ 0.17096345,  0.33056391,  0.53811244]), array([ 0.08941616,  0.13057756,  0.08549415,  1.23515394,  0.27620735]), array([ 1.69062185,  0.55601371,  1.40494991, ...,  2.48426247,
        2.41843612,  2.37813845]), array([ 0.46693602,  0.02700463,  0.69161839]), array([ 0.98284803,  0.20435875,  0.56879258, ...,  0.45329019,
        0.38247778,  0.58895883]), array([ 1.17094086,  1.86998135,  0.40516324, ...,  2.04802661,
        1.68366861,  2.22164556]), array([ 0.35565468]), array([ 0.11051357,  1.94093206,  0.42017437,  1.93846873,  0.11490866]), array([ 0.23832121,  0.16985656,  0.14502155, ...,  0.09553141,
        0.74882909,  0.25167936]), array([ 0.24344661,  0.71604469,  0.57635167, ...,  2.1796533 ,
        3.2387026 ,  2.82588928]), array([ 1.19543841,  1.98482902,  0.80832806, ...,  2.25231686,
        1.6028353 ,  1.72162627]), array([ 1.5,  1. ,  2. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ]), array([ 0.19445951,  0.25506568,  0.12495199, ...,  0.2677989 ,
        0.19560803,  0.39318475]), array([ 0.26885916,  0.51650024,  0.10744766, ...,  0.52832992,
        0.67342854,  0.64594292]), array([ 0.43311113,  0.36389731,  0.49640835, ...,  0.27952325,
        0.22430615,  0.35013033]), array([ 0.88554757,  0.18689302,  0.14018559, ...,  0.16794121,
        0.37962514,  0.57132128]), array([ 1.58438356,  1.51923805,  1.36669108, ...,  2.04041969,
        2.24300986,  1.63742633]), array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , ...,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ]), array([ 1.54588041,  1.13103061,  0.35044258, ...,  2.1321865 ,
        2.13657729,  2.38603541]), array([ 0.22650883,  0.50450223,  0.31563428, ...,  0.27592073,
        0.23753947,  0.22973028]), array([ 0.22088741,  0.40644342,  0.39419824,  0.33696773,  0.16667633,
        0.34639031,  0.15257949,  0.19111842]), array([ 0.0981644 ,  0.2241456 ,  0.23967582, ...,  0.10651878,
        0.2224455 ,  0.34074367]), array([ 1.55110235,  1.0887975 ,  0.86550924, ...,  1.76440479,
        1.48901083,  1.73694595]), array([ 0.38426195,  0.42262158,  0.31236557, ...,  1.87444025,
        2.11489107,  2.39972566]), array([ 1.37938619,  0.66078627,  0.62203798, ...,  2.16635806,
        1.03723973,  0.8222416 ]), array([ 2.06387603,  0.13650092,  1.96042833, ...,  0.05960914,
        0.06356493,  1.379999  ]), array([ 0.27693411,  0.09910222,  0.34492354, ...,  0.16399543,
        0.09848858,  0.17686789]), array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , ...,  0.5,  0.5,  3. ]), array([ 1.87005842]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.5       , ...,  0.83683272,
        1.49475358,  0.        ]), array([ 0.18063015,  0.44328997,  1.01612598, ...,  1.57924484,
        0.6307337 ,  0.56330498]), array([ 1.47563757,  1.07001168,  0.55430136,  0.41983925,  0.23619113,
        0.40562174,  1.41572075,  1.14993152,  1.18746842,  1.68457532]), array([ 0.28687323,  0.29052108,  0.21541588,  0.10160832,  0.06171912,
        0.09023996,  0.1082601 ]), array([ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1.5]), array([ 0.40021619,  0.69313942]), array([ 1.51482309,  2.01856118,  1.96068413,  0.44666123]), array([ 0.1333276 ,  0.0885    ,  0.15088158]), array([ 0.23098322,  0.3935775 ,  0.50150025]), array([ 1.37265746,  0.73863421]), array([ 0.95313929,  1.74625385])]
```

Comment: what have you attempted to do/try yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using numpy you can use

```
np.mean(stepwiseSpeed, axis=1)
```

this will compute the mean of each array in `stepwiseSpeed`

Comment: I think the problem is that the arrays are in the list. If i use your approach i get the error: IndexError: tuple index out of range :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of range based for loops and the length function.

```
avgs = []
for speeds in stepwisespeed:
    sum = 0
    for speed in speeds:
        sum += speed
    avgs.append(sum / len(speeds))
```

Equivelently:

```
avgs = []
for speeds in stepwisespeed:
    avgs.append(sum(speeds) / len(speeds))
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What i need is the average as example of all timepoint 0,1,2... So i need the average of all entrys in the list at position 0 and the average of all entrys of the lists at position 1 and so on. Some list are shorter than others

Comment: I believe I understand and I think my answer still reflects that. If we take a look at the lowermost example of code I posted, it has the list of averages defined as avg, and then, for every array in the list of arrays, it appends the sum of them divided by the number of entries in that array.